# Has Ram Bahadur Bomjon already proclamed that he is a Buddha?

Tags: personal-practice, nirvana

On wikepedia is written that buddha-boy had in 2005 said that he was at the level of a rinpoche. He said that he will need six more years of meditation before he can become a Buddha. So in 2011 he could had become a buddha. But is he still /already living in the bush as a buddha?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Bahadur_Bomjon

Comment: "six more years of meditation before he can become a Buddha" is written in Wikipedia but not in the Telegraph which the Wikipedia article cited as a reference. The Telegraph article gives this quote: "Tell the people not to call me a Buddha. I don't have the Buddha's energy. I am at the level of rinpoche [lesser divinity]. A snake bit me but I do not need treatment. I need six years of deep meditation." FWIW [this](http://maitriya.info/) appears to be a web site devoted to him, which has some news and a biography and messages etc. (though I don't know who is the author of that web site).

Comment: It just goes to show how careful we must be. .From the question I deduced that Ram BB is a fool. From Chris's more careful approach I deduced he is not.

Comment: @PeterJ Maybe we should be more careful when we observe ourselves, especially when we judge others based on limited information. ;)

Comment: @Muuski - I meant we must be careful not to believe Wikipedia and should check our sources.

Answer (score 1):

The international and Nepali media, as well as direct witnesses and victims had described Bomjon as too far from even from a normal ethically firm human beings, far from a law-abiding person and too far from compassion. He had attacked seriously dozens of people, luring his victims to himself through promises of secret initiations. They come to his jungle, for a few days or weeks are loved and cared by his resident "Sangha", and at one point, out of the blue, attacked at Bomjon's order by maroon-robed monks, chained or locked up in his secret houses, beaten with sticks and hands to black and blue, and many of them kept for weeks and even as long as 3 months in his captivity, telling to the outside world that they are in "secluded meditation"! During that, further tortures are inflicted on these victims, if they are women, often even raped and tortured so extremely that two of his victims did not survive. Yet, unfortunately, he has a political backing in his country, and huge money resources, especially from foreign devotees, who are securely kept away from learning the truth.

Have a look at these sights, among many others you can easily Google out:

https://buddhaboymedia.wordpress.com/

http://irregulartimes.com/?s=bomjon

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for someone to attain the Noble Fruits (Streamentry, Oncereturn, Nonreturn, Arahant) but not SammaSamBuddha (Fully Enlightened One) when the Dispensation still exists. From [MN 115](http://tipitaka.wikia.com/wiki/Bahudhatuka_Sutta):

> It is impossible that two rightfully Enlightened Ones should be born in the same world element at one and same time.

Ven. Bodhi's note:

> It's impossible that two Fully Enlightened Ones could arise contemporaneously in one world system: from the time a bodhisatta takes his final conception in his mother's womb until his Dispensation has completely disappeared. Detail at Miln 236-39.

Comment: I think the questions are whether he has proclaimed that he is a Buddha, and whether he is still living in the bush. What you wrote is general doctrine and not any specific/personal information.

Comment: Regardless of what Ram Bomjon said, the original quote says: "He(Ram Bomjon) said that he will need six more years of meditation before he can become a Buddha. So in 2011 he could had become a buddha." It is very important to refer to the Suttas to prevent any misunderstanding of the Buddha's teaching. It's not important to speculate on what an individual did or did not claim. I'll let the original poster decide if the info. I provide is helpful. If s/he says it's not, please feel free to delete my post.

Comment: In 2014 he seem to have been in a kind of fight with people who are disturbing him in his meditation, so probably he is far from buddha? Or can they fight?

Comment: From the Teaching, it's already clear that noone can be a Fully Enlightened Buddha while the Teaching is still here. Whether Bomjon is near or far away from any Noble attainment, who knows! Anyway, does it really matter to you? As long as you yourself wholeheartedly learn and practice what the Buddha taught, what other people did or did not claim is irrelevant..

Comment: Why is it  impossible that two rightfully Enlightened Ones should be born in the same world element at one and same time?

Comment: Because it's already exceedingly rare for even just one Enlightened One to be born at any point in space and time, let alone two.

Answer (score 0):

I am a victim of Ram Bahadur Bomjon, the "Buddha Boy" of Nepal:
Obviously anyone who abducts people, holds them on chains for months (like me), tortures them brutally (like me), rapes nuns (like Ganga Maya Tamang), thrashes people to blood and fractures (like me, Anil Khatri, 9 shepherds, 17 Madeshis of Manarhawa, Jason of Australia, his own mother and siblings) and even kills people (his own sister Manu, a retired US psychiatrist Dr. Moore, and apparently his 5 disappeared nuns and monks Chinimaya Tamang, Fulmaya Rumba, Suresh Ale Magar, Sancha Lal Waiba, Rita Bot) - such a person cannot, at the best will and wish, be even near to anything named Buddha!

If the easily available sources on Google about all these crime accusations are still not enough to you, please watch the videos of respected Buddhist lamas i Nepal who are proving, from the authority of Buddhist teachings, that Bomjon cannot be a Buddha and even less the Maitreya, as he claims:

https://youtu.be/GGgIcF2XAzI
https://youtu.be/vAyXJ0z98B0
https://youtu.be/BqpnFHYRnxM
https://youtu.be/0Y9SG6GNKEQ
https://youtu.be/1Ftjln60UEg